# Magento 2 get websites

Tags: php, magento2

I'm attempting to get all websites to use in a custom template. I've created the following in my block;

```
public function getWebsites()
{
   return $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
}
```

I'm then attempting to iterate over the websites in my template using this;

```
<?php foreach ($block->getWebsites() as $website): ?>
```

When the page attempts to load, i get;

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I've tried every possible variant of this but can't seem to get it working. It's quoted multiple times across numerous forums as being the correct way to retrieve all websites, but it just doesn't work for me.

How can I get an array of websites in my template?

Comment: try `print_r($block->getWebsites())` to see what's in there.

Comment: Sometimes I saw bugs when calling a function in something else. So you could try : `$websites = $block->getWebsites(); foreach($websites as $website):`

Comment: Added this to my template (between <li> tags);
<?php print_r($block->getWebsites()); ?>
I don't get any output, only a single space in the <li>.

Comment: Also tried this;
<?php $websites = $block->getWebsites(); ?>
<?php foreach($websites as $website): ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
I get the same error; Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Can you please post your block file

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $_storeRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository $StoreRepository
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_storeRepository = $StoreRepository;
}

public function getWebsite()
{
    $stores = $this->_storeRepository->getList();
    $websiteIds = array();
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        $websiteId = $store["website_id"];
        array_push($websiteIds, $websiteId);
    }

    return $websiteIds;
}
```